# Why there is no placement delete expression in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator, delete-operator

Why C++ hasn't placement delete that directly corresponds to the placement new, i.e. calls the destructor and calls appropriate placement delete operator?

For example:

```
MyType *p = new(arena) MyType;
...
//current technique
p->~MyType();
operator delete(p, arena);

//proposed technique
delete(arena) p;
```

Comment: doesn't delete automatically call destructor?

Comment: For objects created with placement new no, it doesn't

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a while but this is a very good question and the answers were all way off the mark. This kind of thing shouldn't be about apologizing for shortcomings or rationalizing why the standard committee must not have wanted something just because it isn't there.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783993/placement-new-and-delete

Comment: [Stroustrup's C++ FAQ: Is there a "placement delete"?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#placement-delete)

Comment: @Potatoswatter I agree this is a good question, I'm just guessing why speculative answers sometimes get refused and sometimes accepted, seems there's something like a Elite or a Mafia in there sometimes >)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`operator delete` is unique in being a non-member or static member function that is dynamically dispatched. A type with a virtual destructor performs the call to its own `delete` from the most derived destructor.

```
struct abc {
    virtual ~abc() = 0;
};

struct d : abc {
    operator delete() { std::cout << "goodbye\n"; }
};

int main() {
    abc *p = new d;
    delete p;
}
```

([Run this example](http://ideone.com/0S12FW).)

For this to work with placement delete, the destructor would have to somehow pass the additional arguments to `operator delete`.

- **Solution 1:** Pass the arguments through the virtual function. This requires a separate virtual destructor for every static member and global `operator delete` overload with different arguments.
- **Solution 2:** Let the virtual destructor return a function pointer to the caller specifying what `operator delete` should be called. But if the destructor does lookup, this hits the same problem of requiring multiple virtual function definitions as #1. Some kind of abstract overload set would have to be created, which the caller would resolve.

You have a perfectly good point, and it would be a nice addition to the language. Retrofitting it into the existing semantics of `delete` is probably even possible, in theory. But most of the time we don't use the full functionality of `delete` and it suffices to use a pseudo-destructor call followed by something like `arena.release(p)`.

Comment: Interesting analysis, but still it is unclear to me why an hypothetical e.g. `delete (args...) pointer;` could not be simply resolved to e.g. `pointer->~T(); operator delete(pointer, args...);` (that is, the deleter function would _not_ be called from the destructor directly, as I presume you suggest, but instead a call to the deleter would be introduced by the compiler _just after_ the destructor call).

Comment: @Alek For a polymorphic class, `pointer` is not what should be passed to `operator delete`. Instead it needs a `derived_pointer`. The problem is solvable, but only with a bit of complexity.

Answer (score 8):

Probably because there was syntax for explicitly calling a destructor without deallocation (exactly as in your question), but no syntax for explicit construction in raw memory?

Comment: Explicit construction in raw memory is exactly what placement new is. (The memory may also obtained from something like an `arena` object.) But this answer doesn't draw any actual connection between construction and destruction; the point isn't clear.

Answer (score 8):

Actually there is a placement delete which is called by the implementation for an object that was "allocated" using placement new if the constructor threw an exception.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax#Placement_delete).

> The placement delete functions are called from placement new expressions. In particular, they are called if the constructor of the object throws an exception. In such a circumstance, in order to ensure that the program does not incur a memory leak, the placement delete functions are called.

Comment: Despite the title, I think the question is about the _calling convention_ of the placement delete compared to the _calling convention_ of placement new, not the existence of placement delete.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of placement new is to separate object creation from its memory management. So it makes no sense to tie it back during object destruction.
If memory for your objects is from heap and you want same lifetime for objects and their memory just use `operator new` and `operator delete`, maybe overriding them if you want any special behavior.
Placement new is good for example in vector, which keeps a large chunk of raw memory and creates and destroys object inside of it, but without releasing memory.