# Placement deallocation function is not called

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

The following code I write must invoke both placement deallocation and allocation functions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    void * operator new [] (size_t t, int, int)
    {
        cout << "3 parameters allocation" << endl;
        return ::operator new[](t);
    }

    void operator delete [] (void *p, int, int)
    {
        cout << "3 parameters deallocation" << endl;
        return ::operator delete[](p);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A *a = new (5,5) A[10]; //operator new [] (size_t, int, int) invoked
    delete [] a; //Error. Overload resolution is failed.
}
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/gLJu0d)

5.3.4/22 says N3797:

> A declaration of a placement deallocation function matches the
>   declaration of a placement allocation function if it has the same
>   number of parameters and, after parameter transformations (8.3.5), all
>   parameter types except the first are identical. If the lookup finds a
>   single matching deallocation function, that function will be called;
>   otherwise, no deallocation function will be called.

It is not implement in `C++11` or it is my misunderstanding?

Comment: I thought the placement deallocation function is only called when there's an exception during the construction of the object? [Live example](http://ideone.com/qcM8qj)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14119344

Comment: @dyp Nice example! Thanks! I just don't know about restrictions cited by ecatmur and T.C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a class-specific deallocation function is provided, a *delete-expression* that is not prefixed by the scope resolution operator is ill-formed unless a class-specific deallocation function with one or two parameters is available:

> 10 - If the type is complete and if deallocation function lookup finds both a usual deallocation function with only a pointer parameter and a usual deallocation function with both a pointer parameter and a size parameter, then the selected deallocation function shall be the one with two parameters. Otherwise, **the selected deallocation function shall be the function with one parameter**.

So you need to either:

- provide `void operator delete[](void*);`,
- provide `void operator delete[](void*, size_t);`, or
- write `::delete[] a`.

Comment: §12.5 [class.free]/p4 is probably more relevant. "If the result of the lookup is ambiguous or inaccessible, or if the lookup selects a
placement deallocation function, the program is ill-formed."

Answer (score 1):

```
A *a = new(5, 5) A[10]; 
A::operator delete[](a,5,5);
```

On Visual C++ 2013 this works great

Comment: It contradicts to the Standard.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv What exactly in this snippet contradicts the Standard?

Comment: @dyp I'm sorry. It was my inattention. It seemed an arguments passed into a delete expression.

Comment: eheh no worries I spent 2 days thinking about what could I have done wrong up there

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have access to the original placement new parameters in your `operator delete`, you will have to store them in the allocated memory block and retrieve them later. For example ([Live at Ideone](http://ideone.com/s6JP2o)):

```
struct A
{
    static void * operator new [] (size_t t, int first, int second);
    static void operator delete [] (void *p, size_t t);
    static void operator delete [] (void *p, int first, int second)
    {
        cout << "3 parameters deallocation: " << first << ", " << second << endl;
        return ::operator delete[](p);
    }
};

// simple POD struct to store the placement parameters
struct info {
    int first_param, second_param;
};

void* A::operator new [] (size_t t, int first, int second)
{
    cout << "3 parameters allocation: " << first << ", " << second << endl;
    // allocate sizeof(info) extra space to store the parameters
    auto const p = ::operator new[](t + sizeof(info));
    auto const pinfo = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + t;
    auto const tmp = info{first, second};
    std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tmp), sizeof(info), pinfo);
    return p;
}

static void A::operator delete [] (void *p, std::size_t t) {
    // retrieve the parameters that we stored in operator new [].
    auto const pinfo = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(p) + t;
    auto tmp = info{};
    std::copy_n(pinfo, sizeof(info), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tmp));
    cout << "Deleting with original parameters: " << tmp.first_param << ", " << tmp.second_param << endl;
    ::operator delete[](p);
}
```