# How to clear the memory correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

I have some code:

```
MemoryManager mm;
char *a = new (mm) char [len +1];
```

How can I free all the memory by pointer a?

Comment: What are you trying to do? And there's no need to `delete` the memory pointed to by `a` (if that's what you mean by *free*)

Comment: As @Praetorian, you do not need free memory, because you not allocated memory.

Comment: What is `MemoryManager`?

Comment: @Praetorian: I need to **delete a;** But it will be the memory leak.

Comment: @Eric not really. I have only one pointer. MemoryManager is a class with overloaded operator "new".

Comment: Ok, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857240/why-there-is-no-placement-delete-expression-in-c)

Comment: @user3818229, you use placement new using object locally created, why do you need `delete a;`?

Comment: @Eric 2nd one looks like it answers this question.  Mjölnir used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, there's no way that anything builtin can know how to delete your `a` data - you're the one that allocated it with placement new, so it's your job to clean it up.

Unfortunatly, there doesn't appear to be a way of overloading `delete` for this. Just use a method name of your choice:

```
MemoryManager mm;
char *a = new (mm) char [len +1];

mm.cleanup(a); // since mm allocated us the memory, only it knows how to destroy it.
               // Note that this also needs to do obj.~ClassName() for class types
```

See ['is there a placement delete'](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-delete) in the isocpp faq.

Comment: Can somebody explain this example in more details?

Comment: @gomons: They're creating a `char[]` using a custom memory manager. They want to tell this memory manager to clean up the memory.

Comment: So `char *a = new (mm) char [len +1];` calls `operator new()` overloaded in `MemoryManager`?

Comment: I think it calls `operator new[](sizeof(char[len+1]), mm)`

Comment: and you are right, so I can't understand the sense of MemoryManager class.

Comment: In result, I've concluded the answer is:
`operator delete (a, mm);`
(to call delete like as the usual method)

Comment: @user3818229 You'll want to define that anyhow (in case that the construction throws).  But wait -- what happens if the type has a virtual destructor?  Is the proper `delete` called?  ... so that doesn't work.  `operator delete(a,mm)` *should not call the destructor of `a`*.  Partly because if the constructor of `a` throws, it will be automatically called with a destroyed `a`.

Comment: In short, `operator delete(a,mm)` can only be called after `a.~A()` is called.  It may not call `a.~A()` or it will lead to UB if you use custom placement-new on any type with a throwing constructor.  You could call `operator delete(a, mm, please_destroy_as_well{})` (ie, pass a tag type), but that seems rude.